# Simplify asymptotic $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta} O( \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\delta} + \delta)$ with small $\epsilon, \delta$ and $\delta >> \epsilon^{2}$?

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

Suppose I have a smooth function $F(x, y,   \epsilon, \delta) = \frac{\epsilon f(x)}{\delta y} + g(x) + O(\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\delta} + \delta)$ where $0< \epsilon, \delta << 1$ are small parameters and $\delta >> \epsilon^{2}$. Here  $g$ and $f$ are some smooth bounded functions, expanded in series of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. If I set $F=0$ and rearrange to get

$$y = -\frac{\epsilon f(x)}{\delta g(x)} + \frac{\epsilon}{\delta} O( \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\delta} + \delta)$$

Then can I simplify the last term  $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}O( \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\delta} + \delta)$ ?

If I do so, what do I get? Is it still $O( \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\delta} + \delta)$ or does it change to $O( \frac{\epsilon^{3}}{\delta^{2}} + \epsilon)$ ?

Comment: How did you go from your definition of $F$ to the expression of $y$? There are mistakes: sign, and when you divide the big $O$ by $g$, the $g$ does not disappear (unless you know $0<a\leq g(x)<b$, for instance).

Comment: I set $F = 0$ first and then rearrange.  $g$ is some bounded function with zeroes (of course I ignore singularities): this is formal calculation. My mistake, I omitted the sign, but in the end that's insignicant... What I really need to know is what happens to the $O$ term. P.S. I edited the sign error @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: What makes you believe you can ignore singularities when you divide a big $O$ by a function? If there are singularities "near" the limit point, it's simply wrong (for instance, if you take $x\to\infty$ and $g$ has zeros for arbitrary large $x$).

Comment: Ok, suppose I apply implicit function theorem (IFT) to $F$. Dropping the big $O$ term, suppose I have a solution $x_{0}$ of $F= 0$; this gives me $ y_{0} = -\frac{\epsilon f(x_{0})}{\delta g(x_{0})}$ ; provided that $g(x_{0}) \neq 0$. Then if $DF(x_{0}) \neq 0$, and if $-\frac{\epsilon f(x_{0})}{\delta g(x_{0})}$ is bounded, then IFT gives that for small $\frac{\epsilon^{2}}{\delta}$ and $\delta$ the solution may be continued.  I write the solution as in my question above. Is this ok? Note that I emphasise $g(x) \neq 0$ for some neighbourhood of $x_{0}$. @Jean-ClaudeArbaut